# How can we upload log files from a failed .msi install (Using WiX to create)

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer

We have a problem with our current installer for a browser plugin where a small percent of our users try to install it but the .msi install fails. The issue is we can't get the logs back from them as it is an anonymous download and our QA computers aren't getting this issue. We know they fail as we have log file in JS from before the download and a survey response after saying they tried to install it.

I have searched around but haven't found an answer on how to have an automatic upload of log files on failure of a windows .msi install.

The best solution I have seen is in WiX, we can create a shell script action after the install and then use PowerShell or bitsadmin to try to upload a specific log file from the commandline if we can find it in the temp directory, however this does not seem to be a clean or reliable solution.

Being able to PUT or POST it anywhere would be fine.

Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the [MsiLogging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370322.aspx) property to something like "voicewarmupx", you can later use the property [MsiLogFileLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370321.aspx) to get the log file location. This supported in Windows Installer 4.0 and higher.

If a batch file or PowerShell script isn't giving you the programmability you need, you can [create a custom action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev%5Cextensions%5Cauthoring_custom_actions.html) that retrieves the log file and sends it to you.